# PHP: How to retrieve original value from hashed / encrypted email address

Tags: php, encryption, bcrypt, password-hash

I am new to PHP and hope someone can help me with this.

I use PHP to hash / encrypt an email address as follows:

```
$email = "someEmail@someProvider.com";
$emailHashed = password_hash($email, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

This works as intended and creates a string with 60 characters.

Can someone tell me how I can retrieve the email from this or what is the reverse way to get the original unhashed and unencrypted email from `$emailHashed` ?

I couldn't find a way to fix this myself.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. Hashes are *one way*. You shouldn't be hashing email addresses.

Comment: Thanks. Even if the hash was created on my computer ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024702/how-can-i-decrypt-a-password-hash-in-php

Comment: Since this is only about emails (not passwords) is there another way of encryption in PHP that I could use here and that would allow me to retrieve the original value ?

Comment: It doesn't matter where it was created.

Comment: Can I get the cow back from the beefburger? Even if the beefburger was created on my own farm?

Comment: [Here's how to do two way encryption with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448256/encrypting-decrypting-file-with-mcrypt/2448441#2448441)

Comment: @MarkBaker: Good explanation - thanks. :) Just added a comment above (and getting hungry now).

Comment: For encryption, you can use [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker: Thanks - if I use mcrypt for the email how can I retrieve it back then ?

Comment: mcrypt has a [decrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php) function

Comment: @JohnConde I'd recommend [this instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262109/php-simplest-two-way-encryption/30189841#30189841).