# add customer username in woocommerce email template

Tags: email, templates, woocommerce

I am overriding the woocommerce admin new order template. I am looking to add the customer's username and if possible password as well.
Can anyone please help me.

```
<?php $user_info = get_userdata(1);
echo $user_info->user_login;?>
```

I am currently using this code but it's not working as intended.

Comment: Hi! Can you please share the code you're currently using? What steps have you taken so far? What's blocking you exactly?

Comment: '<?php $user_info = get_userdata(1);
            echo $user_info->user_login; ?>' , I am currently using this code but it's not working as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$order` variable inside the template which is an instance of [WC_Order](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order.html) to obtain the user by calling the method `get_user`. This will return an instance of [WP_User](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/) or false if they choose to not create an account.

The WP_User instance has a method called `get` which you can use to obtain the username, password and any other data you require.

```php
$user = $order->get_user();

if($user){
    $username = $user->get('user_login');
    $password = $user->get('user_pass');
}
```

Comment: Hi brother, Thanks for sharing this code it helped me achieve what I was looking for. There is one problem I am getting hashed password with this code. Can you please help me with how to unhash that?

Comment: You cannot unhash the passwords stored in the database. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24024772/14481105